# normal map baking artifacts Blender ----> Substance Painter

Tags: texture-baking

I have a model (High poly & Low poly) exported as FBX from Blender 2.78 to be textured in Substance Painter , the problem is whenever I bake the normal map for the model and use a metal material (basic material just metal at 1 and roughness at 0 ) it looks fine in the view port , but when I render an image (in Iray or Cycles) some artifacts appear .

I tried to increase the resolution for the baking as well as the final output normal map , but that does not help .

I created a simple scene to show the problem .

here is the High & Low poly model file : [image]

this how it looks in Substance Painter real-time view port vs how it looks in Iray & Cycles :

[image]

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Please upload your .blend file(s) internally using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. It allows the .blend files to stay permanent for future research on similar issues by other users, and there are people out there who don't like to download from 3rd party sites for whatever reason.